# Changing folder structure during npm publish

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I have a node module with the following structure:

```
src
 - folder1
 - folder2
 - ...
dist (Will be generated by grunt)
 - folder1
 - folder2
```

I want to publish only the contents of dist folder to npm registry. In my package.json, I am using the files field to pickup only dist folder.

```
files: ['dist/**']
```

The above pattern is picking up the folder dist also. I want only the contents of the dist folder and not the dist folder. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by using the glob defined below:

```
files: ['dist/**', '!dist']
```

- `!dist` would match the folder and indicate that it should not be included.
- `dist/**` would match all the contents of the `dist` directory.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. That is excluding the dist folder all together.